# phpmyadmin: Cannot login with a user who is not root (Access denied for user + PHP was built without openssl extension, can't send password encrypted)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

## Problem

I cannot login to phpmyadmin with a user who is not the root-user.

## Description

I installed a Webserver with XAMPP, a MySQL-Server 8.0.12 with the Community-Installer and phpMyAdmin 4.8.2 (PHP 7.2.8).

**Logging in to phpmyadmin with the root-user works fine.**

I added a new user in the MySQL Workbench:

> Username: web 
>      Authentication Type: Standard 
>      Limits To Hosts Matching: localhost
>      Password: strongpassword

I try to login from the same machine.

**But when I do one of the following things, I get the later listed errors.**

- Trying to login with a incorrect password or a incorrect username
- Trying to login to any user who is not root (even when the password is correct)

> Cannot log in to the MySQL server
>
> mysqli_real_connect(): PHP was built without openssl extension, can't send password encrypted
>
> mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'web'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

### Extract from my config.inc.php

```
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'longstringwithmanyletters';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
```

I have now row like "user" or "password" or "extension".

### What I tried already using the search function

1. I have only one MySQL open
2. I changed localhost to 127.0.0.1
3. I changed auth_type from `cookie` to `http`
4. I added the row `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';`
5. I added the rows `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';` and `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'myrealrootpassword';`
6. I deleted and editeted new users multiple times (in phpmyadmin with my root-user and in the MySQL Workbench)
7. I tried the phpmyadmin 5.0+ snapshot

### My thoughts

Maybe it has something to do with SSL (i have no SSL) or with the MySQL-extension because when I enter a incorrect password, I get a MySQL-error instead of a "wrong password"-error. But however the root user works.

### Edit #1

I added the following code to the config.inc.php:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl'] = true;
```

Now the error "mysqli_real_connect(): PHP was built without openssl extension, can't send password encrypted" is no longer showing up. The other errors are still there.

## Different problem which might belong to this one

When I try to create a user in the phpmyadmin interface (User Accounts > Add User Account), the user gets created but without any password an with the following error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'REQUIRE NONE WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_' at line 1

The SQL code:

```
CREATE USER 'peter'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password AS '***';
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'peter'@'localhost' REQUIRE NONE WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0;
```

This is why I created the new users in MySQL Workbench.

Comment: WHat version of `phpMyAdmin` are you using. There are occasional versions with issues

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention. phpMyAdmin 4.8.2 | MySQL 8.0.12 | PHP 7.2.8

Comment: With MySQL 5.7 everything works fine.